# How to use 2 between in a SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to get data from a SQL Server database between two dates and two times of the day but I don't know how to use two `between` in a `SqlCommand`.

This is what I've tried

```
public void getData()
{
    SqlCommand SelectSpecificDataTL = new SqlCommand("Select * from cash where Date between @InitialDate and @FinalDate and where Time between @InitialTime and @FinalTime", database.cash);

    database.cash.Open();

    SelectSpecificDataTL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InitialDate", dateTimePickerIDate.Value);
    SelectSpecificDataTL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinalDate", dateTimePickerFDate.Value);
    SelectSpecificDataTL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InitialTime",Convert.ToDateTime(txtInitialTime.Text));
    SelectSpecificDataTL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinalTime", Convert.ToDateTime(txtFinalTime.Text));

    SqlDataAdapter SpecificData = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectSpecificDataTL);
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    SpecificData.Fill(data);
    database.cash.Close();
}
```

I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

Comment: you are using between just fine, you have extra `Where` clause : "from cash where Date between @InitialDate and @FinalDate and **where** Time between"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select * from cash where Date between @InitialDate and @FinalDate and Time between @InitialTime and @FinalTime
```

You can write only one `where`!